# Cannot start JRuby rails 3.0.10 app on Torquebox with mysqljdbc driver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, torquebox

I 'm getting error message shown below on deploying rails 3.0.10 app on Torquebox server installed as a gem. Same error on both development and production modes.  However, it works fine without Torquebox if i run a command "rails server -b 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -e development". Not so sure something specific to Torquebox server.

ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: no connection available: SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL=0

### Settings

database.yml has

development:

adapter: jdbcmysql
username: root
password: 123
host: localhost
database: gidm_dev

Gemfile has

gem 'activerecord-jdbc-adapter'
  gem 'activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to determine the issue without more information. Would you be willing to join us on IRC (#torquebox on freenode) so we can work with you to figure it out? If IRC doesn't work for you, can you send an email to the TorqueBox user's list with the full log output from `torquebox run` along with your rails log?

More information about the IRC channel and mailing list can be found at http://torquebox.org/community/.

Comment: Thank you. I have added logs from Torquebox and Rails @ https://issues.jboss.org/browse/TORQUE-557

Comment: BTW, I have not problem with MSSQL-JDBC driver.

Comment: Fixed by Torquebox team through IRC.  Use 'mysql' gem.